# How to update views outside of update/insert transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index

[Looking at SQL Server indexed views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx) I see that these views are updated within a transaction that updates dependent tables. I wonder if there is a way around it?

There will be about 10 views with 20 indexes that depend on the same table. I don't want to wait for updating views and indexes on views when I do an update on dependent table. I want to be sure that tables are updated within a transaction and views are updated after in some kind of a daemon mode.

Comment: Maybe you should consider whether you are over-using indexed views, rather than whether SQL Server should change its behavior to suit your scenario? 10 views with 20 indexes for a single table? Perhaps you are doing far too much reporting in your OLTP database.

Comment: Is it possible for you to just use non-materialized views. This will keep you from having your inserts and updates from being incredibly slow and if your table is indexed properly you should still see pretty speedy returns on your queries.

Comment: Aaron, completely agree with you. It is over-use of indexed views. The idea was to eliminate joins for super-fast queries, but we are not ready to pay write time for that. I have put the idea aside and trying to find smth more suitable for requirement: very-fast query/sort on about 1 to 50 properties on a collection over 10m records with frequent updates...

Comment: Zane, so main idea of my research is eliminating joins. We suppose them to slow-down queries/sorts. There are about 3 tables with 10m records and 3 more tables with 1m.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't. The [C (Consistency) in ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_%28database_systems%29) dictates that the dependent (indexed) views are updated.

If you want to workaround this, you'd need to build views on a separate table that is updated on demand in your own time. Say via Service Broker or scheduled

Comment: They say Oracle can do that, so I am looking for the same functionality in MS SQL

Comment: @Denis: yes, Oracle can but SQL Server can't. Personally, I don't want to use out of date views. And I've seen issues with Oracle backends for apps that have deferred-update materialised views, it's quite counter intuitive in my opinion

Comment: @Denis Oracle MVs really aren't that similar to MS SQL indexed views—what they have in common is skin-deep.

Comment: @Denis are you checking things off of some master feature list? Or have you actually *used* the feature in Oracle?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I _have_ used this feature in Oracle - it does remove concurrency contention. As such, it is highly useful in the cases where slightly stale data is OK.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov I understand that some people have used the feature, and that it is appropriate for very specific use cases. My question was whether this specific OP wants this feature in SQL Server because that's his actual use case and he knows that it will work, or if it's just a checklist item.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov "stale data is OK" sounds a lot like the type of justification I see a lot for `NOLOCK`. Yes it is ok sometimes, but you must be fully aware of - and OK with - the potential consequences.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the following sounds wrong: "it is appropriate for very specific use cases". In fact, it is highly useful in many very common cases, when indexed views are completely useless because of lock contention. Have you worked with Oracle in real life high concurrency OLTP?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov I haven't seen very many "common cases" where users are ok with stale data. It seems that you can avoid indexed views altogether if you don't want to keep them current. I guess we work in different application spaces entirely.

Comment: Aaron, this is just a point in my check list. I am not keen on DBs. Looking for alternative...